# Swagger package javax.validation.constraints does not exist

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm having trouble building swagger Java clients using `swagger-codegen` and Maven. It's building on my CI using Java 1.8 and Maven 3.6. I'm seeing this:

```
... package javax.validation.constraints does not exist
... package javax.validation does not exist
```

The relevant part of my config is:

```
{
  "library": "resttemplate",
  "configOptions": {
    "dateLibrary": "java8"
  },
  "useBeanValidation": true
}
```

And the command I use to generate the api is:

```sh
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i swagger.json -l java -o ./generated/ -c swagger-java-config.json
```

I would expect this error to occur with Java 11. Also, I don't see the required imports in the [official `resttemplate` library `pom.xml` template for the Java client](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/Java/libraries/resttemplate/pom.mustache).

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from `"useBeanValidation": true` in the configuration. This option is only available for generated servers, not clients. The `java -jar swagger-codegen.jar config-help -L java` will show this option as it does not discriminate on the `library` chosen (in your case `resttemplate`). The templates specific to `resttemplate` do not alter the code outputted by the `java` language templates.